# Is it possible to write good papers in a startup?

Tags: industry, independent-researcher

I don't know if there are some small startups in the world where they hire researchers to write papers. If so, is it possible for them to write good papers almost without advisors and professors or even doctors? What they only have is probably the open source materials like papers on Axive and Sciencedirect and etc..

I have never encountered any small company having research department only for publishing papers. Is it common?

Comment: How are they making money? The cost of a single employee in a small firm is a huge part of the total cost, what does that paper-writing employee add to the profits of that firm to justify those costs?

Answer (score 4):

A small startup will not have any money for hiring a person to write papers or form an independent research department.

Yet you can see startup companies appearing as author affiliations on academic papers, so a question might be how that is possible.

What happens is that some startups are funded out of research activities at universities, and at least during an initial growth phase they keep a tight connection to the university they are funded out of. Typically that would work in the way that a university research group develops a technology, and maybe a PhD student or post-doc working on that funds a company to commercialize the technology. Nevertheless, the research group may continue improving or working with that technology, and if that is in collaboration with the company, then of course company members will appear as co-authors on the papers coming out of that.

In that case, also the professor who originally supervised the research would also stay in contact with the company, usually even in some formal role such as on an advisory board, and would thus be available for further academic support.

Comment: _What happens is that startups are funded out of research activities at universities_ -- I'd suggest modifying this to say "that **some** startups are funded out of research activities at universities".

Comment: @MadJack That's right of course.

Comment: @silvado maybe in some countries the government is supporting them?

Comment: @lerner Yes, this can either be specific funding programs aimed at small company, or through universities who get a budget to support companies funded out of their research.

Comment: agree, very common practice, it is called Start up incubators.